# Converting 3.3V logic to 5V logic with two common emitter transistors in series

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, switching, level-shifting

I am working with digital signals.  I would like to know if there is any alternative to boosting a 3.3V logic signal to 5V logic only using transistors.

I am currently using two common emitter amplifiers in series in order to do this. Would other methods work better than this? If not, why is this a good method?

[image]

Comment: Whether this is good enough will depend on many things... what are you driving with the 5V digital output? How fast? Do you care about power consumption?

Comment: I do not care about power consumption. I am driving a microcontroller working on 5V logic and the signal is coming from an XBee at the rate of 38400 bps. It is currently working flawlessly but I need to motivate why - for a research paper.

Comment: Engineering is all about tradeoffs such as power, speed, noise, etc. It seems that your applications is not very demanding, so your main tradeoff is time! If you understand the circuit and it is working fine, don't spend more time on it. I would say this circuit is rather power-hungry and not particularly fast, but for your usage it's fine.

Comment: R2 is unnecessary in your circuit. A similar functionality could be achieved with a single nMOS and 2 resistors (google "I2C Level Shifter" for examples).

Comment: @brhans why would using a single nMOS prove to be better than this?

Comment: Because it's fewer parts and works just as well. [Example](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bi-directional-logic-level-converter-hookup-guide/all)

Comment: There are plenty dedicated IC's that will do this - You don't need to over complicate your effort.   Digikey shows over 2700 options    https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/logic-translators-level-shifters/732

Comment: Coming back to your circuit, R2 should really be moved over to the base of Q1 where it would actually be necessary to limit base current there.

Comment: One issue with the circuit given is the output logic HIGH is a "weak" signal...  It works by turning Q2 off, then R3 will 'pull' the output high.  That means any current that is driven into the load must pass through R3.   If it's a high-impedance load and consumes microamps, it's probably a non-issue.   But if the load demands any non-negligible amount of current, that resistor could become an issue.  For example, if your load wants a very meager 0.1mA, pass that through 10k, you would lose E=I*R=0.0001*10000=1V (meaning the output is 1V below your target).

Comment: @KyleB thanks for your answer! The load is one input pin of a PIC16F1937 microcontroller. I guess it is not a problem since it works.

Comment: If it's connected to a microcontroller GPIO, why use two transistors? Use one and invert in software. Or just use a 74HCT logic gate, 4 to 8 level shifters for the price of one logic chip, hard to beat

Comment: Since you're driving a micro's GPIO you might be able to eliminate your R3 by enabling the micro's port pin pull-up instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question as stated isn't really a great fit for EE.SE since you're really asking for opinions, but here's a brief commentary on your circuit as well as some alternatives.

Firstly, your circuit:

1. R2 as you have it placed between Q1 & Q2 is unnecessary. A resistor in that position is typically used to limit the base current of the transistor, but in your circuit that current is already limited by R1.
2. You should have a resistor on the base of Q1 to limit base current there. If you apply a 3.3V logic signal to the input without a base resistor you'll overload both Q1 and whatever is attempting to drive it.
3. Since you're using this circuit to drive a micro's GPIO input, you might be able to eliminate R3 by enabling the micro's internal port pin pullup resistor on that input.

Some alternatives:

1. The common "I2C Level Translator" circuit
   Similarly to your circuit, this one's R2 could potentially be eliminated by enabling your micro's internal input pullup. It has an advantage over yours of requiring fewer parts. R1 could probably also be eliminated if the device which drives 'Input' actively drives it high (instead of just letting it float high as is the case with I2C).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjgpcfm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2. Truncated version of your circuit
   Since you're driving a micro's input, you could use a single transistor and then invert the logic level in your micro's firmware, and you also have the option of eliminating the 5V pullup resistor if you enable your micro's internal input pin pullup.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fflIOem.png)</sup>

3. Use a 74HCT-series buffer like a [74HCT244](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hct244.pdf?ts=1654558013602&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FSN74HCT244) for 8 lines in one package.
   Even though it runs on a 5V supply, it'll quite happily interpret 3.3V logic inputs since its  V<sub>IH</sub> and V<sub>IL</sub> are 2V and 0.8V respectively.
   If you don't need 8 lines and want to save space, then there's a single-line [74HCT1G125](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT1G125.pdf) in a little 5-pin package, or a 2-in-one [74HCT2G125](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT2G125.pdf), and remember that these options do not require any external resistors.
   If the non-inverting 74HCT244 are hard to come by, then you could consider its inverting cousin the [74HTC240](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hct240.pdf?ts=1654587999405&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) and invert the logic level in your micro's firmware.
4. The easiest option of all: Do nothing.
   Look at the datasheet of your microcontroller for its V<sub>IH</sub> (High-level Input Voltage) and V<sub>IL</sub> (Low-level Input Voltage) specifications.
   There's a very good chance that your micro will have similar specs to those 74HCT logic gates in option 3, and will quite happily accept 3.3V logic input levels with no buffering or level-shifting needed.